# android c2dm third party application server configuration(windows or linux)

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

In android i am developing a for c2dm push-notification.And get idea about push-notification from http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/.And now i need some suggestions for third party application server.what are requirements and configurations for that third party app server.

Can we use windows server as third party app server??which one is better to use linux server or windows server??
Help needed urgently..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well basically you can take what ever server you like. All you need to do on your application-server is provide an interface to store the device specific C2DM-information like device registration id and send an HTTP-Post on Google's C2DM Server to trigger a push-notification.

Possible solution:

Windows Server with Apache Tomcat and Server implemented using Java including Servlets to provide an interface for device registration.

Answer (score 0):

http://souravtechdiary.blogspot.in/2012/03/implementing-push-notifications-for.html

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks.but i need suggestions for third party server which can communicate with c2dm  server.Please reply if you have any suggestions